# RedirectToAction in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.net MVC 4
I have a controller following:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //todo something.........
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(PersonModel model)
    {
        //todo something.........
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id); // => Okay
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //todo something............
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PersonModel model)
    {
        //todo something........

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = model.Id } ); //=>Okay
        //return RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id); // => exception???, but Edit Action is Okay**
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: is it NullReferenceException in Create ?

Comment: What is the **question**?

Comment: Yes, NullReferenceException.
why happened exception with Create action?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'HelloWorld.Controllers.PersonController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the exception because the `RedirectToAction` Method has 6 signatures and when you write `RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id);` it can be considered as a string and will search for a controller with the name `model.Id`.
Have a look here [MSDN:RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Hope it will help you

Comment: But why dosen't Edit Action throw exception?

Comment: You have two `Edit` actions. When it doesn't throw exception it because you use the Get: ` public ActionResult Edit(int id)
   {
      //todo something.........
   }
` and when You redirect you use the Post:`[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Edit(PersonModel model)
   {
      //todo something.........
      **return RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id); // => Okay**
   }` which will throws an exception

Comment: In [HttpPost]Edit Action doesn't throw exception, but in [HttpPost]Create Action will throw exception.

Comment: Yes It will throw an exception when you call Edit Action with parameters not expected

Answer (score 0):

By default MVC supports 'ID' andnot 'id' or any other:

In your code ::

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    //todo something.........
}
```

here you have declared `int id`
because of that ::

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id);
```

this is not working.

If you have been declared your Edit action as::

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
    //todo something.........
}
```

then you can use this::

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { @Id = model.Id } );
```

Comment: I debug in visual studio, model.Id is not null, and add data is sussecfull

Comment: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'HelloWorld.Controllers.PersonController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter

Comment: If Model.Id is null, "return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = model.Id} );" also will throw exception, but it run okay

Comment: @KhangTran Have a quick look in my edited suggestion

Comment: @KhangTran the Querystring you passed is 'id' and not 'ID'
that is why you are getting error there

Comment: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)'..."
   I don't think that, because in [Post]Edit Action doesn't throw exception. Only with [Post]Create Action

Comment: @KhangTran Can you put your Edited code in your question by editing it?

Comment: Sorry @Rahul RJ, I'm researhing Nopcommerce project and I'm getting this problem. so the source is very large. I can create a simple example for this problem. :)

Comment: @KhangTran don't put the whole source code,
Just edit the code you have putted in your this question.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it as your code. and I also get exception so that."The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)'..."

Comment: @KhangTran you have to pass it as--------------- return RedirectToAction("Edit",new{@Id= model.Id});

Comment: If you use RedirectToAction("Edit" new {id = model.Id})  in [post]Create Action is not exception, no problem in this case :), but I don't understand diffrent between RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id) in [post]Edit Action and in [post]Create Action. Why doesn't in Edit Action throw exception as Create Action.